# QtWebPageRenderer SIGILL issue

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, fedora

My problem is summed in title. When I call method `setHtml` on instance of `QtWebPageRenderer`, SIGILL signal is emitted and my application goes down.

I'm aware that this issue is caused by bad Qt5 dynamic library but I installed it with:

```
sudo pip install PyQt5 --only-binary PyQt5
sudo pip install PyQtWebEngine --only-binary PyQtWebEngine
```

so I thought I will get correct precompiled library. When I tried to install PyQt5 without `--only-binary`, I always ended with some strange compilation error. Something like `qmake` is not in PATH even though it is and I'm able to call `qmake` from shell.

So my question is, how to make PyQt5 running on Fedora 31 without any SIGILLs.

EDIT:

Following code can replicate the issue. That information about SIGILL is little inaccurate because first signal is actually SIGTRAP, after I hit `continue` in gdb, I got SIGILL. This hints that Qt is actually trying to say something to me, although in not very intuitive way.

After some playing around with it, I found that without thread, its ok. Does this mean that Qt forces user to use QThread and not python threads? Or it means that I can't call methods of Qt objects outside of thread where event loop is running?

```
import signal
import sys
import threading
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage


class WebView(QWebEnginePage):
   def __init__(self):
      QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
      self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finish)

   def print_result(self, data):
      print("-" * 30)
      print(data)
      with open("temp.html", "wb") as hndl:
         hndl.write(data.encode("utf-8"))

   def on_load_finish(self):
      self.toHtml(self.print_result)


class Runner(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, web_view):
      self.web_view = web_view
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.daemon = True

   def run(self):
      self.web_view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"))


def main():
   signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   web_view = WebView()
   runner = Runner(web_view)
   runner.start()
   app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I probably failed to be concrete, but my main concern is that pip downloaded bad precompiled library, which, when used, will invoke illegal instruction failure from the deep frame somewhere in qt dynamic library.

Yes I can provide reproducible example, but it makes no sense. Regardless of how bad you will use pyqt, it will not fail with SIGILL and I know its exactly this error because I tried to run it in gdb.

Comment: I want to test what you indicate but I do not have the code that generates that error, so if you provide a simple MRE then it is easy for me to analyze where the problem is. For my test I plan to use docker.

Comment: ok then, I will create that MRE

Comment: aaaaand created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have several restrictions:

- A QObject is not [thread-safe](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html#thread-safety) so when creating "web_view" in the main thread then it is not safe to modify it in the secondary thread
- Since the QWebEnginePage tasks run asynchronously then you need a Qt eventloop.

So if you want to use python's Thread class then you must implement both conditions:

```py
import signal
import sys
import threading
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage


class WebView(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finish)

    def print_result(self, data):
        print("-" * 30)
        print(data)
        with open("temp.html", "wb") as hndl:
            hndl.write(data.encode("utf-8"))

    def on_load_finish(self):
        self.toHtml(self.print_result)


class Runner(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        # The QWebEnginePage was created in a new thread and 
        # that thread has an eventloop
        loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
        web_view = WebView()
        web_view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"))
        loop.exec_()


def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    runner = Runner()
    runner.start()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

In reality `QThread` and `threading.Thread()` are native thread **handlers** of the OS, so in practical terms it can be said that QThread is a `threading.Thread()` + `QObject` with an eventloop running on the secondary thread.

---

On the other hand, if your objective is to call a function from a thread to which it does not belong, then you should use asynchronous methods as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62315639/6622587).

In this case the simplest is to use pyqtSlot + QMetaObject:

```
import signal
import sys
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage


class WebView(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finish)

    def print_result(self, data):
        print("-" * 30)
        print(data)
        with open("temp.html", "wb") as hndl:
            hndl.write(data.encode("utf-8"))

    def on_load_finish(self):
        self.toHtml(self.print_result)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QUrl)
    def load(self, url):
        QWebEnginePage.load(self, url)


class Runner(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, web_view):
        self.web_view = web_view
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        url = QtCore.QUrl("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(
            self.web_view,
            "load",
            QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,
            QtCore.Q_ARG(QtCore.QUrl, url),
        )


def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    web_view = WebView()
    runner = Runner(web_view)
    runner.start()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Or functools.partial() + QTimer

```
from functools import partial
import signal
import sys
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage


class WebView(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finish)

    def print_result(self, data):
        print("-" * 30)
        print(data)
        with open("temp.html", "wb") as hndl:
            hndl.write(data.encode("utf-8"))

    def on_load_finish(self):
        self.toHtml(self.print_result)


class Runner(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, web_view):
        self.web_view = web_view
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        wrapper = partial(
            self.web_view.load,
            QtCore.QUrl("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"),
        )
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)


def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    web_view = WebView()
    runner = Runner(web_view)
    runner.start()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for very complete answer, I used the trick with timer. Very simple and readable.